# Incline curl difficulty

Tags: exercise, muscle, biceps

I was doing this inclined curl [source](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/Biceps/DBInclineCurl.html)

What i found that i could curl 25 pound with normal curl but with incline curl I can do only half of that, what is reason for decrease in strength ?

Answer (score 1):

The form makes your arms stretch further than when doing normal curls. This makes it so that the curl starts from a dead hang at the bottom, which makes it harder.